# Ajax div change fadeOut

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to:

1. show load content from X.div
2. on click a nav div fade out content
3. load content
4. show new content

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#allcontent').load('data/home.html');

       $('.hovers').click(function() {
          var page = $(this).attr('href'); 
          $('#allcontent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
             $(this).load('data/' + page + '.html').show();
          });
          return false;
       });
   ```

Why is this not working?

Here's my fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4jyq/1/)

Comment: Could you put some HTML in your JSFiddle please? :)

Comment: Also loaded url doesn't exist. Could you please put some real page there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part would be:

```
$('.hovers').click(function() {
   var page = $(this).attr('href'); 
   $('#allcontent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
   $(this).load('data/' + page).show();
});
```

Since the js can load the pages that don't have a reference to `.html` or other file extensions. Just `attr('href')` is enough.

And the remaining part is correct!

Plus: You need to check whether the source location exists or not, you can use Browser's inspector for that. Please press <kbd>F12</kbd> and there in the Network tab, you can check for each page load, and its HTTP code, if there is 404, then the file is not present and you need to test the link. You will find other helpfull material there too.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your fast response i will test it now :)